# how to Run sudo command in a Bash script

Tags: shell-script, sudo

I just need to restart tor service at startup the script is simple as that :

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo service tor restart
```

But I want to execute it without taking my password at every startup.

I followed these posts : https://askubuntu.com/questions/425754/how-do-i-run-a-sudo-command-inside-a-script/425990

and I changed my sudoers file with this :

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script
```

But as I try to execute it in terminal, the script always ask me for password.
I also try the others answers in this post but as that post as no validation I didn't find a solution. If someone have a solution ?

Comment: What operating system are you using? If Linux, what distribution? If this needs to be run at startup, why don't you just set the tor service to start on boot?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what you need. Do you just want tor to be started every time the machine reboots?

Comment: @terdon I find an answer and I think the question can help the community. The reason why I ask this question is minor and I think touch less people. And I learned things :)

Comment: OK, but the answer you got is really not a good way of starting a service at boot, if that's what you want. It means any user on the system will be able to restart tor with no password. For a cleaner way, see [How to write startup script for systemd](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/47715)

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point. I use service tor with `FoxyProxy` in `Firefox`. For a reason I don't know I need to restart `service tor` if I want to load pages with `FoxyProxy` enabled by default. But if I understand the answer, my `service tor` start one time and just after restart with my username and just allowed for `service tor`. This could be another post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script
```

gives `username` the right to run the script with `sudo`, as in

```
$ sudo /path/to/script
```

If you want the user to be able to restart `tor` specifically, with `sudo` in the script, use

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service tor restart
```

Now the script may do

```
sudo /usr/sbin/service tor restart
```

Note that this command has to correspond exactly to the `sudo` configuration.

Comment: When I save the sudoers file it says that there is a syntax error at the line I did modifications

Comment: @Gy0m The path to the command has to be specified exactly. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, that is the right answer now it load without asking the password :) I have a last interrogation : is it safe to do that ?

Comment: @Gy0m Note that the script will have to use the exact same command with `sudo`.

Comment: This way works perfectly for my intention, but I'm also asking myself about security  issue that could happened as terdon says

Comment: @Gy0m Yes, I only addressed the issue relating to `sudo`, and did not say anything about starting services at boot. Since I'm not a Linux user, I am not the right person to give an authoritative answer of that part, but terdon linked to  another question that may help you.

Comment: Thanks, you perfectly answer at this specific question. I'll make my own research about security questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would be NOT to use sudo in the script.

1. wring the script without the use of sudo
2. chmod script file to root and take all permissions away from user and others.
3. Run the script with sudo